# Reading value and coordinates of every pixel post NDVI calculation in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, ndvi

I have a pre forest fire image and a post forest fire image. I would like to make a comparison between the coordinates and the values of both images pixel by pixel.

How would I access the value and coordinate of each pixel, post NDVI calculation in ArcGIS?

Comment: Why not just use raster calculator to subtract post-fire NDVI from the pre-fire?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your raster to points using the Raster to Point tool in ArcToolbox-Conversion Tools-From Raster - Raster to Point.  This tool may result in a fairly large feature class depending on how many pixels your image has.  After conversion you might use the add geometry tools to populate the attribute table with coordinate values if you needed to.

Comment: I did this and it works. Now I would like to get the cell value using getCellValue management tool, however if I have 100,000 points, then I would have to select the X and Y of the point for all 100,000 points manually. Is there a way to run some Python code that gets the cell value for all of the points?

Comment: @Ayugma Acharya. The Raster to Point tool has on option called Field.  This should allow you to add the value of the underlying raster to your point feature class.  Did this not happen for you?